# Best way to isolate a Rubik's Cube from background

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I have been working on a python program using opencv that will help the user solve the Rubik's Cube.  The most important & complicated part is identifying the cube to read the value of each of its sides.

I have had a decent amount of luck so far but am wanting to change the processing pipeline a little.  I think it would make sense to isolate the cube from its background before trying to detect the (rounded) square stickers and read their colors.

Attached is an example of the sort of frame we would be dealing with.  I'm not sure what the best method for isolating the cube from the background would be.  I have tried background selection, which seemed somewhat promising (though the mask was very grainy & blotchy).  But I am also wondering if it would make more sense to use something like object detection.

[image: this is how the cube will be positioned in the camera]

I have considered just making a "dumb" crop which makes the user align the cube within a reticle.  However, I would prefer a more elegant solution and don't mind spending the additional time that entails.

Edit: maybe the mild bokeh could be used to identify the background, or is it too miniscule to detect consistently?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: do you want to crop just this image, or any image of the cube in a similar background?

Comment: It would be any image of this cube, with pretty similar but not identical backgrounds.  The program (currently) accepts a video feed and will need to see all six sides of the cube.

Comment: Do you want the whole cube or the 9 white faces?

Comment: whole cube as in 6 sides of 9 squares

Comment: I will check that page out.

Comment: hmm, that isn't really what I am trying to do.  My intention was to apply the mask before detecting/recognizing the squares, rather than after doing so.

Comment: I ended up mostly figuring it out, masking out the background didn't end up being worth doing.